# mongodb: find all records by condition in other documents

Tags: mongodb

Not sure how to formulate the task correctly in words.

Say there are such documents in a collection:

```
  {id:1, type: 'added' },
  {id:1, type: 'completed' },
  {id:2, type: 'added' },
  {id:3, type: 'added' },
```

Find all documents with type `added` for which doesn't exist records with the same `id` and `completed`

So it would find only:

```
  {id:2, type: 'added' },
  {id:3, type: 'added' },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$id",
    "types": { "$push": "$type" }
  }},
  { "$match": {
    "types": {
      "$in": ["added"],
      "$nin": ["completed"]
    }
  }}
])
```

[**Output**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6goidjIT8xC)

```
[
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "types": [
      "added"
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "types": [
      "added"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks! How heavy is this query if there are millions of records? What indexes are needed to make it viable?

Comment: @WHITECOLOR `$group` stage doesn't use index. So in terms of performance this query is too expensive.

Comment: so and there are no other ways to make it more performance-wise?

Comment: @WHITECOLOR You have to do this at the time of document insertion.

Comment: Not sure I got your comment, what is meant by "do this at the time document insertion"?